# How to have different login pages for same authentication model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I have one Django user model (with a custom user manager) but two different user types, namely `Store` and `Customer`, to handle authentication:

**authentication/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...

    # checks if user is associated with a store object
    def is_store(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'store')

    # checks if user is associated with a customer object
    def is_customer(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'customer')
```

**stores/models.py**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.RESTRICT, primary_key=True)
    ...

    def clean(self):
        # validates that the selected user doesn't belong to a customer object
        if self.user.is_customer():
            raise ValidationError({'user': _('This user is already associated with a customer.')})
```

**customers/models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ...

    def clean(self):
        # validates that the selected user doesn't belong to a store object
        if self.user.is_store():
            raise ValidationError({'user': _('This user is already associated with a store.')})
```

Now, the stores and customers should use two different websites to login in i.e. stores will use *admin.domain.com* while customers will simply use *domain.com*. If a store is logged into *admin.domain.com*, will it also show that he is logged in when he visits *domain.com*? If so, how can I prevent this and isolate these two models to specific sites, while using the same authentication model and methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `permission_classes` to accomplish above problem.

DRF has `permission_classes` attribute which supports list of permission class .
Create 2 permission classes `IsShopUser` and `IsShopCustomer`. Both class will be child of `IsAuthenticated` class which is build in DRF.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
class ISShopUser(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        if user is a shop user return true
        else return false
        """
```

in each view apply, those permission classes based on user type.

```
class ShopAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [ISShopUser]
```

It is not recommended to log out users if they enter the wrong API. Simply show an error.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 mixins StoreUserOnlyMixin and CuustomerUserOnlyMixin inheriting from django TemplateView class. Then in each of then override dispatch method.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

class CustomerUserOnlyMixin(TemplateView) 
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_customer():
            auth.logout(self.request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('customer_login_view'))
        return super(CustomerUserOnlyMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And something similar with StoreUserOnlyMixin. After that you can inherit from one of them based on if view should be accessible by Store or Customer

Comment: I am using the django-rest-framework views, so should I still inherit the TemplateView or is there another class I should use?

Comment: Also, is there not a way to keep both types of users logged in, but instead view them as logged out when they try to visit a domain/page not intended for them?

Comment: It depends on how do you want to write your code, I would inherit from GenericViewSet  because you can add model mixins like RetrieveModelMixin etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "view them as logged out"? If you add this dispatch method to your Viewset it will logout User and redirect User to correct login page